# Визуальное оформление приложения в Android

Tags: ui, android

День добрый, вот у меня возник вопрос, я не так давно начал программировать под Android... И хотелось бы узнать какими методами добиваются такого красивого визуального оформления, с помощью стандартных кнопок - я пока не научился как делать, очень привлекает градиет в центре и нижняя часть приложения =) Может быть именно Вы расскажите куда копать или ссылки на статьи как это реализуется, потому-что по по запросу "Свои UI у Android приложения" я грубо говоря ничего не нашел =) Спасибо, жду Ваших советов.
[image]

Comment: На чём Вы программируете под андроид? Язык, библиотеки, sdk?

Comment: Android SDK из под Eclipse. Качал с оффициального сайта пакет в 400 мегабайт

Comment: Ну так надо было это указать. я на QtCreator пишу, там в Qt стилями всё делается, так что смотрите библиотеки, которыми создаёте виджеты.

Comment: у этого дизайна куча проблем.

 - кнопки внизу, особенно home
 - размеры указанны в непонятных единицах.

Почитайте [это](http://www.androiduipatterns.com/). Если хочется фон-градиент - [вот](http://www.christianpeeters.com/android-tutorials/android-create-gradient-background-via-xml/).

Comment: обычно подразумевается, что используют стандартный sdk. Еще есть поделки, к примеру PhoneGap, но об этом пишут.

Comment: а в чем приемущество писать скажем под тем-же QtCreator / PhoneGap ?

Comment: Вам нужно погуглить на тему "android sdk style button" или что-то похожее, к примеру вот посмотрите, надеюсь, поможет или наведёт на мысли: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4489069/android-button-style

Comment: под PhoneGap - то, что человек знает JavaScript и не может осилить Java. У QtCreator - то, что он может делать нативный код. Да, он стает процессорнозависимым, но для некоторых приложений можно получить сильный выигрыш в скорости.

Comment: @KoVadim а PhoneGap сможет использовать GPS? или для такого лучше использовать тот-же QtCreator ?

Comment: не знаю про PhoneGap, могу сказать только, что в Qt заявляют http://qt-project.org/search/tag/gps и обсуждают http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41698-QT-in-Android-Example-for-accessing-the-GPS-Service

Comment: Может ли PhoneGap? может и может, webkit ведь может.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу градиента можете почитать тут: [Drawable. Изображения, фигуры и градиенты](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/shape.php).

Для нижних кнопок можно использовать 2 фона (с подсветкой и без) и переключаться через `selector` (описывается в `XML`). Если `Button` не получится так кастомизировать в крайнем случае
создайте нужный вид в `LinearLayout` и в коде повесте на него `OnClickListener` (будет как кнопка работать)

Answer (score 1):

Статья о создании своих элементов интерфейса под андроид.
сорри только инглиш [Жмакать сюда](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCustomViews/article.html)